# Monodevelop crash on create new GTK# project

Tags: linux, monodevelop, gtk#

I just have installed monodevelop from Debian (sid) repository and I am actually unable to use it. When I try to create new gtk# project, it crashes immediately:

http://pastebin.com/FN6htN48

Do you have any idea how to make it working?

Comment: I would suggest using a version of Monodevelop from Debian stable, reporting a bug to Debian, or asking on Super User.

Comment: @ptomato I used the version from the debian repository, and got this exact same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this same error from the Debian package monodevelop (Version 5.10). I found this bug report, and a reply from the developers https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=57533:

> Thanks for the bug report. MonoDevelop 5.10 is pretty old and
>   deprecated, although many distributions are still shipping it.
>
> You can find an updated MonoDevelop version at
>   http://www.monodevelop.com/download/linux/, there is a preview build
>   available via flatpak or you can get a more recent MD 6.0 (still
>   deprecated) from our package repository
>   (http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-lin-debian).

I did the above, got version 7.5 Preview, and this particular issue was fixed.